# Haskell type classes and instances

Tags: haskell, type-inference, typeclass, functor

Why does the code below require a constraint and the type parameter for an instance of `Show` but are they need required for making `Quad` an instance of `Functor`?

```
data Quad a = Quad a a a a 
instance (Show a) => Show (Quad a) where
  show (Quad a b c d) = show a ++ " " ++ show b ++ "\n" ++ 
                        show c ++ " " ++ show d
instance Functor Quad where 
  fmap f (Quad a b c d) = Quad (f a) (f b) (f c) (f d)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your definition of `Show` requires `show` be applied to each value wrapped by the `Quad` data constructor, which imposes the constraint. It would not be needed if you had a trivial instance like

```
instance Show (Quad a) where
    show (Quad a b c d) = "some Quad value"
```

because this definition doesn't *care* about the type of `a` et al.:

```
> show (Quad 1 2 3 4)
"some Quad value"
> show (Quad (+1) (+2) (+3) (+4))
"some Quad value"
```

---

`fmap`, on the other hand, has type `(a -> b) -> f a -> f b`, because `fmap` itself places no constraint on the type used by `Quad`; any such constraints are imposed by whatever function is passed to `fmap` as its first argument:

```
> :t fmap
fmap :: Functor f => (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
> :t fmap show
fmap show :: (Functor f, Show a) => f a -> f String
```

---

Sometimes, an instance for `Functor` *will* require a constraint. For example, consider the `Compose` type from `Data.Functor.Compose`:

```
data Compare f g = Compose { getCompose :: f (g a) }
```

Ignoring its name, all it requires is two type constructors with kind `Type -> Type`. But, if you want a `Functor` instance for `Compose`, then those type constructors must also have `Functor` instances, because we'll use `fmap` internally.

```
instance (Functor f, Functor g) => Functor (Compose f g) where
    -- x :: f (g a)
    fmap f (Compose x) = Compose (fmap (fmap f) x)
```

For example, `fmap (+1) [1,2,3] == [2,3,4]`, but `fmap (+1) [[1,2,3], [4,5,6]]` wouldn't typecheck, because `(+1)` can't take a list as an argument. `Compose` lets us "dig into" the nested functor.

```
-- Compose [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]] :: Num a => Compose [] [] a
> fmap (+1) (Compose [[1,2,3], [4,5,6]])
Compose [[2,3,4],[5,6,7]]

-- Compose [Just 3, Just 4, Nothing] :: Num a => Compose [] Maybe a
> fmap (+1) (Compose [Just 3, Just 4, Nothing])
Compose [Just 4,Just 5,Nothing]

-- Compose Nothing :: Compose Maybe g a
> fmap (+1) (Compose Nothing)
Nothing

-- Compose (Just [1,2,3]) :: Num a => Compose Maybe [] a
> fmap (+1) (Compose (Just [1,2,3]))
Compose (Just [2,3,4])
```

Comment: Very detailled. Much appreciated. Understand now.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `show` on the type "inside" Quad so it needs to be an instance of `Show` but you aren't calling `fmap` on the values "inside" Quad in your definition of `fmap` on `Quad` so there is no reason to require it is an instance of `Functor`.